# IE6 Text Resize in JavaScript Modal

Tags: javascript, text, resize, internet-explorer-6

I am having an issue where IE6 will not re-size the text in a JavaScript generated modal window. If I leave the parent page text size at medium open the modal window and then re-size the the text to largest, the text becomes cut off in the modal window. If I close the modal window and leave the text size at largest, then re-open the modal window, the text is fine. It appears to be an IE6 redraw issue.

Has anyone else run into this issue.

NOTE: The company I work for still supports IE6, so that is why I am looking for a solution in IE6.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following your question. Are you saying that the window doesn't resize or the text? You seem to say that the text *does* resize as it's being cut off, so are you expecting the opened window to resize with text zoom?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The text does not re-size. The modal window is fixed height and width.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer my lie in the "modal" part. Modal means you should not be able to do anything else until this dialog is "taken care of". Might be easier to not allow such operations while modal windows are open?

"Restrictive or limited interaction due to operating in a mode. Modal often describes a secondary window that restricts a user’s interaction with other windows. A secondary window can be modal with respect to its primary window or to the entire system. Compare modeless.
[msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb226821(VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb226821(VS.85).aspx)"